# Well pump isn't functioning after chlorination shutdown

Tags: electrical, plumbing, wiring, repair

We had to bleach our well, and we turned off the the power to the pump overnight. After letting the chlorinated lines set for about 12 hours, I flipped the breaker to the pump to drain the lines. Unfortunately, nothing drained from the lines and I realized something was not working.

I checked the pressure in the well tank, it is fine. I checked the pressure gauge on the pressure switch. It reads 0. I tested the pressure switch circuit and power is hot on both the source and load side. Does this mean the pump is receiving power but not working?

Answer (score 1):

When I have had submersible pumps fail they have always tripped the overload or breaker. If you have a pump controller the start capacitors may be bad but this usually blows a fuse in the controller and you would not have power on both legs if 240V. Try turning the pump power off for 30 minutes if it is over heated it may reset if it has a thermal overload on the pump. Then try toggling the power on and off several times to get the pump to try and start. If it starts you should be prepared to replace the pump because once they start failing to start with good capacitors (if it has them) it wont last long.